# How to upgrade google play app?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phone not updating Market to Google Play?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20405/phone-not-updating-market-to-google-play)

I'm having 3.4.4 of google market. But google has change it to google play and upgrade it's app to 3.4.7  But it doesn't upgrade when I launch it.
How to upgrade it? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't update itself on launch, the update would come over the air at some convenient (for Google) occasion. I don't think you can control this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Google will push this update automatically... but not at app launch. So, just wait.

There're ways to do this [manually](http://www.techpetals.com/download-play-store-3.4.6-apk-4538), but that's not guaranteed safe. Play Store is just a re-branded version of Market app. There's no change at all. You'll find only icon & label changed wherever involved.

[image: Google Play Store]